# Fatal Error: File 'hdf5.mod' opened at (1) is not a GNU Fortran module file

Tags: gfortran

I am using gcc 4.9.2 and trying to use gfortran in order to read and write hdf5 binary files. I am getting the following error:

USE HDF5

```
  1
```

Fatal Error: File 'hdf5.mod' opened at (1) is not a GNU Fortran module file

I tried removing and reinstalling gfortran but no change. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: What gives you the indication that `hdf5.mod` is a Fortran module? It's simply a binary file format. The `.mod` extension doesn't make it a Fortran module, any more than giving a `.txt` file a `.jpg` extension makes it an image file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HDF5 library (or at least, the Fortran interface part of it) needs to be compiled with the corresponding Fortran compiler and (major) version that you use for your own code as well.